# Angular: How to re-bind to previously selected object when list changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

By default, when you modify the source list that a `select` is bound to using `ng-options`, it clears the selected list item even if that item exists in its entirety in the new list. I figure there may be a way to tell angular that if they have the same `WhateverKey` property, then consider them the same item and don't de-select. Is there a way to do this?

In the example below, selecting a new customer re-binds (think: re-downloads) the list of possible locations, but the selected location (`$scope.Location`) still exists in the new list, and thus user experience intuition says it should be selected.

**I understand the problem is that it's literally a different reference object with a different angular object key.** I'm asking how to auto-rebind based on a property of the object (in this case, `LocationKey`) without resorting to looping through JavaScript to find the corresponding object in the new list manually.

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.Customers = [{CustomerKey: 1, CustomerCode: 'Customer1'},
                      {CustomerKey: 2, CustomerCode: 'Customer2'},
                      {CustomerKey: 3, CustomerCode: 'Customer3'}];
  $scope.Locations = [{LocationKey: 1, LocationCode: 'Location1'},
                      {LocationKey: 2, LocationCode: 'Location2'},
                      {LocationKey: 3, LocationCode: 'Location3'}];
  $scope.Customer = $scope.Customers[0];
  $scope.Location = $scope.Locations[0];
                      
  $scope.SelectCustomer = function() {
    $scope.Locations = angular.copy($scope.Locations);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <select ng-model="Customer"
          ng-options="c as c.CustomerCode for c in Customers"
          ng-change="SelectCustomer()"></select>
  <select ng-model="Location"
          ng-options="l as l.LocationCode for l in Locations"></select>
  <div ng-bind="'Customer: ' + Customer.CustomerCode"></div>
  <div ng-bind="'Location: ' + Location.LocationCode"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.SelectCustomer = function() {

  $scope.Locations = angular.copy($scope.Locations);
  $scope.Location = $scope.Locations.find(function(loc){
    return loc.LocationKey === $scope.LocationKey;
  }
}
```

Sorry for the lazy answer. Would have been a comment if you could format code properly in a comment.

Comment: That doesn't work. You're implying that the `LocationKey` is equal to the index, which isn't true here (it's off by 1) and definitely wouldn't be true in a live environment where the keys are arbitrary numbers.

Comment: Oh, you are right of course. Updated with an ES6 answer. Of course, this is also not "without resorting to looping through JavaScript to find the corresponding object in the new list manually."